# let f be a continuous function such that $f(0)\le1$ and for all real x, $f(x)^2 - 3f(x) + 2 \ge 0$. Prove that $f(x)\le 1$ for all real x

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Question:

let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(0)\le 1$ and for all real $x$, $f(x)^2 - 3f(x) + 2 \ge 0$. Prove that $f(x)\le 1$ for all real $x$.

I think you would start by factorising to get $(f(x)-2)(f(x)-1)\ge0$ and then $f(x)\ge1$ but I'm not really sure where to go from there? I think maybe you can use the intermediate value theorem but I'm not exactly sure how. TIA

Answer (score 1):

Factorizing is a good start. Suppose now, there were some $x$ with $f(x) > 1$. By the intermediate value theorem due to $f(0) \le 1$, there is some $x_0$ with $1 < f(x_0) < 2$. But then $$\bigl(f(x_0) - 2\bigr)\bigl(f(x_0) - 1\bigr) < 0$$
Contradiction.